# How to thumbnail/preview doc, docx, odt and other document files in dolphin?

Tags: kde, dolphin, thumbnails, previews, document

I was searching some places but couldn't find any solution as to how preview document files like odt, ods, doc, docx in dolphin. Is there any solution to this? I would actually need this because I workin with many ohter people and a lot document stuff.

Thanks Benjamin.

Kubunut 16.04
Dolphin 15.2.3

---

Okay in Konqueror the preview of odt, ods, docx etc. is working very good. But i didn't manage to get the calligra 3.0 stuff working. It is quite complicated to compile the required packages, i must confess. Is there another way to install the packages without doing the cmake compiling stuff? Calligra 3.0 has not been implemented into the backport ppa, as far as I see.

Best, Benjamin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**KDE thumbnails**

The KDE applications can show a thumbnail for a file if there is a thumb creator plugin installed for the file type.

For the documents (odt, ods, doc, docx) the thumbnailers are distributed from the Calligra project: https://www.calligra.org .

**Ubuntu repositories**

Few picks from the Ubuntu 16.04

words_msword_thumbnail.desktop -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/calligrawords-common

sheets_ods_thumbnail.desktop -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/calligrasheets

These are for the KDE4. They won't work with the Dolphin build with the KDE Frameworks 5 (KF5).

A workaround is to install the dolphin4: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/dolphin4

or use the Konqueror file manager: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/konqueror .

Older - Dolphin/Dolphin4/Konqueror: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?69160-Dolphin-Video-amp-Pdf-Files-Preview

**Backports**

Kubuntu developers are distributing backports through a PPA: http://kubuntu.org/news/

I'm not sure if they have the KF5 Calligra.

Comment: Installing Calligra 3.0 on Kubuntu 18.04 solved the issue. Thumbnailing now works with all mentioned file formats. Thanks for the help!